# How to Construct IdentityResult With Success == true

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, rhino-mocks

I have a class with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager injected, and I want to expect the userManager.CreateAsync(user, password) method to return a Task where the IdentityResult.Succeeded = true. However, the only available constructors for IdentityResult are failure constructors that will cause Succeeded property to be false.

How does one create an IdentityResult that has Succeeded == true? IdentityResult doesn't implement an interface and Succeeded isn't virtual so I don't see any obvious ways of creating a mock object through Rhino Mocks (which i'm using as my mocking framework).

My method does something like the below. Providing this example to show why I might want to mock this.

```
  public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(NewUser newUser)
    {
        ApplicationUser newApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = newUser.UserName,
            Email = newUser.Email
        };

        IdentityResult identityResult = await applicationUserManager.CreateAsync(newApplicationUser, newUser.Password);

        if(identityResult.Succeeded)
        {
            someOtherDependency.DoSomethingAmazing();
        }

        return identityResult;
    }
```

I'm trying to write a unit test that ensures that someOtherDependency.DoSomethingAmazing() is called if identityResult.Succeeded is true. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sounds like a case for a decorator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Yeah I was really trying to reserve that as a last resort. There are a number of methods that return IdentityResult so it would be a pain to wrap all of these.... but I may just have to.

Comment: As @jaytre mentioned, use var result = IdentityResult.Success will give you an IdentityResult object with Succeeded = true

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Would the static IdentityResult.Success property work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityresult.success(v=vs.108).aspx

**Edit**:
To add some more detail, it seems what you want to do is get your mocked CreateAsync to return an IdentityResult where Suceeded is true. For that I would just return IdentityResult.Success from your mock. There's shouldn't be a need to mock the IdentityResult itself.

**Example**: How to setup a service that returns Successful identity result.

```
    applicationUserManagerMock.Setup(s => 
        s.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())
    ).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);
```

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting here? I need to force the Success value to be true for my test.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken with what you want to do, but I would mock out CreateAsync to return IdentityResult.Success. I don't think there's a need to mock out IdentityResult. Just CreateAsync to provide the functionality that you're expecting.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what this was. The static property actually returns an IdentityResult that is successful. Weird. Anyway, that is indeed exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth stating more clearly - the way to get a "Succeeded" result is to use the IdentityResult.Success static property to generate the instance of the result with Succeeded == true. It is the only way I can see to get a +ve response.

Comment: What about returning an `IdentityResult` that failed?

Comment: Been a while since I used this code, but I think `return new IdentityResult("FAILED");` would do it... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dn315342(v%3dvs.108)

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Unable to get IdentityResult
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387380/asp-net-core-unit-test-mock-usermanager-createasync-and-return-identity-result

Answer (score 24):

To make the Succeeded property equal to True use either of these examples:

```
return IdentityResult.Success;
IdentityResult result = IdentityResult.Success;
```

Comment: This is the anwer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Further more, to make the Success property returns true

```
return Identity.Success;
```

Then in your implementing code, call the implementing method like this

```
var result = await RegisterUser(newUser).Result
if(result.Succeeded)
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Approach is different for **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** and **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity**. Bellow I provided solutions for both:

1. If you are using **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** namespace please
   check following approach:

   In my example I mocked `IdentityResult.Success` in following way:

   First, IdentityResult has protected constructor:

   ```
   protected IdentityResult(bool success);
   ```

   Protected constructor can be accessed from inherited class if you
   implement like this:

   ```
       public class IdentityResultMock : IdentityResult
       {
           public IdentityResultMock(bool succeeded) : base(succeeded) { }
       }
   ```

   Second, in my unit test I configured `ResetPasswordAsync()` to
   return identityResult like in below:

   ```
   var identityResult = new IdentityResultMock(true);
   _mockUserManager.Setup(e => e.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password)).ReturnsAsync(identityResult);
   ```

   Third, in my controller's action `ResetPasswordAsync()` will returns
   result with `Successed == true`:

   ```
   var result = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
   ```

   Basically I implemented new class which inherited IdentityResult and
   used that in my test cases.
2. If you are using using **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity** namespace
   then try following approach:

   `IdentityResult` in this case does't have protected constructor but
   it has protected property `Succeeded` which can be accessed within
   class who inherited `IdentityResult`.

   We can achieve like in following example:

   ```
   public class IdentityResultMock : IdentityResult
   {
       public IdentityResultMock(bool succeeded = false)
       {
           this.Succeeded = succeeded;
       }
   }

   var result = new IdentityResultMock(true);
   Console.WriteLine(result.Succeeded);

   result.Succeeded = true; // This is not allowed! Please use constructor.
   ```

Comment: I tried this but in the public IdentityResultMock(bool succeeded) : base(succeeded) { } I am getting error "IdentityResult doesn't take a constructor with one argument".. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: @Alexander I am not sure what did you try but `IdentityResult` has protected constructor which accept bool. Please see source code: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/IdentityResult.cs Did you use from namespace: `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity namespace. And I find no constructor accepting bool succeeded. For aspnetcore, is this done differently?

Comment: @Alexander It looks like that `IdentityResult` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` namespace has only default constructor. It means that my solution will not work for that case :(

Comment: @Alexander I updated answer which has solution for AspNetCore as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var responseTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);

_mocAuthService.Stub(s => s.RegisterUser(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(responseTask);
```

If you need a successful IdentityResult then all you need to do is call the Success property. This will give you a successful IdentityResult.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityresult(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Could you provide some context for the answer? Code is good, but an explanation of the code is even better.

Comment: Updated the answer with a comment, hopefully will make it clearer